# Data Flow/Process Diagram Query

Tags: uml, dataflow, dataflow-diagram

I'm looking to depict a flow of data which shows the following:

- Booking made into Reservations sytem by customer
- Data is then transformed, validated and merged in the Reservations system
- It is subsequenlty extracted into a flat file to be consumed by down-stream systems
- Some of the downstream systems then do a secondary transform of the data

Can someone recommend the most effective way of showing this both from a data, systems and process perspective?

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is not very good as it does not show any research effort, is too broad, and does not include any code etc. Anyway, see my answer below and also this help article: http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers (and the neighborhood at the right side of the screen, especially the top most and the 2nd top most)

Answer (score 0):

For your homework question, probably the most effective way for you would be to Google out some examples and select the ones that resemble your homework. You should be able to find quite few exactly the same homework booking, reservation examples with ...diagram and ...diagram and ...diagram.

My recommendation for the place to start learning is [Kirill Fakhroutdinov](http://www.uml-diagrams.org/about.html)'s site

:boom: → http://www.uml-diagrams.org/index-examples.html ← :stuck_out_tongue_winking_eye: